# Wordpress rest API to get post by multiple categories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am using Wordpress API, i am trying to pull post where category should be 3 and 6 but when i am using endpoint /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=3,6.

But instead of showing post where both categories are available, it is showing posts belongs to any of the above category.

Example

POST1 -Category3, Category6

POST2 -Category3, Category5

In above example instead of showing POST1, API Is showing both posts.

Comment: You can't do that with the query parameters only. You need to use a filter: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/ Here is more information: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-rest-api-cat-1-and-cat-2/

Comment: If you're looking to get posts from ALL categories passed instead of any single category, try this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/365405/122776

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pass the values like this:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=3&categories=6
```

Comment: You're right. I tested it again and it only seems to work when there's an unique post in one of these categories.

Answer (score 1):

query params should be like

1. you will be using the v2 API
2. categories param will either accept slug or category ( you can check WordPress API documentation )
3. category ids are numeric
4. slugs are strings

   **wp-json/wp/v2/categories=category_1_id,category_2_id,category_3_id**

   **wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=608372504,608249267**

https://example.net/wp-json/wp/v2/categories=category_1_id,category_2_id,category_3_id

https://example.net/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?slug=amazon,walmart&orderby=count

https://example.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=608372504,608249267